# How to fix SDL2 'Assertion failure at SDL_RenderClear_REAL' in C++?

Tags: c++, macos, runtime-error, sdl-2

I'm learning the basics of creating a window using SDL2 by following a tutorial. The code works just fine, and even compiles correctly, however on runtime it gives the error message 'Assertion failure at SDL_RenderClear_REAL'.

I've tried reinstalling SDL2, as well as moving it to the user library folder on my mac, but neither of these fixed the issue

**main.cpp**

```
#include "game.hpp"

Game *game = nullptr;

int main() {

    game = new Game();

    game->init("GUI", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

    while (game->running()) {
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }
    game->clean();
    return 0;

}
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include "game.hpp"

Game::Game(){}

Game::~Game(){}

void Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) {
    int flags = 0;
    if (fullscreen == true) {
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Sub-systems initialized\n";

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if (window) {
            std::cout << "Window created.\n";
        }

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

        if (renderer) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            std::cout << "Renderer created\n";
        }

        isRunning = true;
    } else {
        isRunning = false;
    }

}

void Game::handleEvents() {

    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

void Game::update() {

    cnt++;
    std::cout << cnt << "\n";

}

void Game::render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Game cleaned\n";
}
```

**game.hpp**

```
#ifndef game_hpp
#define game_hpp
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

class Game {

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool running() { return isRunning; }

private:
    int cnt = 0;
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};

#endif
```

After narrowing down the code, it seems that the issue is limited to SL_RenderClear. Here's the exact message it produces in the console:

```
2019-08-20 15:26:15.508900-0500 GUI[26436:7287503] WARN: 

Assertion failure at SDL_RenderClear_REAL (/Users/valve/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.10-source/src/render/SDL_render.c:2235), triggered 1 time:
  'renderer && renderer->magic == &renderer_magic'
Program ended with exit code: 42
```

How can I fix this issue?
EDIT: Added full code to help identify the problem.

Comment: `SDL_Renderer *renderer;` is a pointer. Pointer gonna point, but right now it don't point anywhere useful.  There's going to be a call you need to make in order to get a valid `SDL_Renderer` instance.

Comment: According to this example: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer you are supposed to initialize the SDL_Renderer using SDL_CreateRenderer

Comment: Which requires a `SDL_Window` provided by `SDL_CreateWindow`, so there's extra work you need to do before you can start clearing.

Comment: Without the full code is difficult to understand what is going on, but given the way you can repro, can it be that you have some codepaths that do not initialize the renderer and despite this you always pass it to SDL_RenderClear ?

Comment: I did initialize the window and the renderer while following the tutorial, but it didn't still gave the same error. Also, here is the tutorial in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44tO977slsU. Going to go over it again to see if I missed something along the way.

Comment: Well I realized I was being foolish. It turns out I didn't call my init function. Called it and now everything works. @_@

Comment: Not related to question, but your event handling is incorrect. You didn't check returm value of `PollEvent` and there may be multiple events in a queue. `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))`  is a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic "hello world" of creating a window and clearing the color on the screen for SDL requires a few boilerplate initialization steps

1. Initialize SDL
2. Create a SDL_Window
3. Create a SDL_Renderer

After which you can do
SDL_RenderClear and use SDL_RenderDrawColor to set a custom color to make it more obvious that it is properly clearing the Renderer.

***Without error checking*** this would look something like:

```
SDL_Init(flags);
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("window title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, more_flags);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, red, green, blue, alpha);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
```

Also remember to call SDL_Delay(ms) if you want the program to not immediately close before you get a chance to see the window.

Comment: Don't forget to test the return values for success. Sucks to think you have a valid window when you don't.

Comment: Well I realized I was being foolish. It turns out I didn't call my init function. Called it and now everything works. Took the fourth rewrite of the code for me to realize I forgot it. @_@

Comment: The window does now popup and work fine. However, on closing it it gives the same error.

Comment: Quitting SDL requires a few other functions be called. SDL is a C library so you need to explicitly call functions that lets SDL know it is time to free the memory. Namely, SDL_Quit, SDL_DestroyWindow, SDL_DestroyRenderer. Furthermore, if you want it to properly poll input events you need to use SDL_PollEvent

Comment: It seems that it gave that error on closing because I destroyed the window before I destroyed the renderer.

Comment: @MacProgrammer You may find [`std::unique_ptr` coupled with a custom deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to call the correct disposal function handy for managing the lifetime of SDL's data blocks.